# Angularjs testing D3 directive compile bug

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, svg, d3.js, angularjs-directive

I have an angularjs directive containing some D3 code. This directive works perfectly when used in the application. My problem occurs when I compile this directive for test purposes, a part of the code generated in the svg of D3 is generated twice : the nodes and paths.

Here is the html page using this specific directive (project-graph):

```
<div>
        <div ng-controller="GraphController as graphCtrl">
            <projects-graph
                    options="graphCtrl.options"
                    colours="graphCtrl.colours"
                    data="graphCtrl.data">
            </projects-graph>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the test generating the directive (I removed some code not relevant):

```
describe('The graph directive', function() {

   var scope, compile, q, window, ctrl;

   beforeEach(module('app'));

   beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $rootScope, $q, $window){
      q = $q;
      window = $window;
      compile = $compile;
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
   }));

it("display all nodes and paths given in the data", function() {

scope.data = {
  "nodes": [
    {"id":123, "name": "P1", "type": "Project"},
    {"id":5, "name": "P2", "type": "Project"}
  ],
  "paths": [
    {"source":123, "target":5}
  ]
};

var graph = compile(angular.element('<projects-graph  options="options" colours="colours" data="data"></projects-graph>'))(scope);
scope.$digest();

console.log(graph);
expect($(graph).find("circle").length).toBe(2);
});

});
```

The expecting code that should be generated inside the directive is :

```
<projects-graph options="options" colours="colours" data="data" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">
<svg id="graphSvg" width="1500" height="800">
    ...
    <path class="link dragline hidden" d="M0,0L0,0"></path>
    <g><path class="link" style="marker-end: url(#end-arrow);"></path></g>
    <g>
        <g><circle class="node" r="40" style="fill: rgb(200, 200, 200); stroke: rgb(140, 140, 140);"></circle><text x="0" y="0" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" class="id">P1</text></g>
        <g><circle class="node" r="40" style="fill: rgb(200, 200, 200); stroke: rgb(140, 140, 140);"></circle><text x="0" y="0" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" class="id">P2</text></g>
    </g>
</svg>
</projects-graph>
```

But what I get is :

```
<projects-graph options="options" colours="colours" data="data" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">
<svg id="graphSvg" width="1500" height="800">
    ...
    <path class="link dragline hidden" d="M0,0L0,0"></path>
    <g><path class="link" style="marker-end: url(#end-arrow);"></path></g>
    <g>
        <g><circle class="node" r="40" style="fill: rgb(200, 200, 200); stroke: rgb(140, 140, 140);"></circle><text x="0" y="0" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" class="id">P1</text></g>
        <g><circle class="node" r="40" style="fill: rgb(200, 200, 200); stroke: rgb(140, 140, 140);"></circle><text x="0" y="0" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" class="id">P2</text></g>
    </g>
    <g><path class="link" style="marker-end: url(#end-arrow);"></path></g>
    <g>
        <g><circle class="node" r="40" style="fill: rgb(200, 200, 200); stroke: rgb(140, 140, 140);"></circle><text x="0" y="0" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" class="id">P1</text></g>
        <g><circle class="node" r="40" style="fill: rgb(200, 200, 200); stroke: rgb(140, 140, 140);"></circle><text x="0" y="0" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" class="id">P2</text></g>
    </g>
</svg>
</projects-graph>
```

As you can see the path and circle groups are generated twice. Any idea ?

Comment: could you provide a jsfiddle or a plunkr? thx

Answer (score 0):

change

```
var graph = compile(angular.element('<projects-graph  options="options" colours="colours" data="data"></projects-graph>'))(scope);
```

to

```
var graph = angular.element(
  '<projects-graph options="options" colours="colours" data="data"></projects-graph>'
);
compile(graph)(scope);
```

Comment: Is there a good reason why it would work with your code and not with mine ? It seems you only separated the instruction in two steps ?